# Google Analytics trackEvent for Internal Links not Working Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I am using ga.js. My code is recording for some internal links but on the pages that I have tested the internal links of showed for total events of 1 when it should have been 50.  I also look at real time reports in the events.  All of my externals show up right away but my internals do not.  I cannot figure out why everything works except for the internal links.  My code is as follows,

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
                jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                    var pdffiletype = /\.(pdf)$/i;
                    var filetypes = /\.(zip|exe|doc*|xls*|ppt*|mp3)$/i;
                    var baseHref = '';
                    if (jQuery('base').attr('href') != undefined)
                        baseHref = jQuery('base').attr('href');
                    jQuery('a').each(function () {
                        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
                        if (href && (href.match(/^https?\:/i)) && (!href.match(document.domain))) {
                            jQuery(this).click(function () {
                                var extLink = href.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, '');
                                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'External', 'Click', extLink]);
                                if (jQuery(this).attr('target') != undefined && jQuery(this).attr('target').toLowerCase() != '_blank') {
                                    setTimeout(function () { location.href = href; }, 200);
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else if (href && href.match(/^javascript\:/i)) {
                            //do not track
                            return true;
                        }
                        else if (href && href.match(/^mailto\:/i)) {
                            jQuery(this).click(function () {
                                var mailLink = href.replace(/^mailto\:/i, '');
                                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Email', 'Click', mailLink]);
                            });
                        }
                        else if (href && href.match(pdffiletype)) {
                            jQuery(this).click(function () {
                                var extension = (/[.]/.exec(href)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(href) : undefined;
                                var filePath = href;
                                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'PDF', 'Click', $(this).html(), 0]);
                                if (jQuery(this).attr('target') != undefined && jQuery(this).attr('target').toLowerCase() != '_blank') {
                                    setTimeout(function () { location.href = baseHref + href; }, 200);
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else if (href && href.match(filetypes)) {
                            jQuery(this).click(function () {
                                var extension = (/[.]/.exec(href)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(href) : undefined;
                                var filePath = href;
                                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', 'Click-' + extension, filePath]);
                                if (jQuery(this).attr('target') != undefined && jQuery(this).attr('target').toLowerCase() != '_blank') {
                                    setTimeout(function () { location.href = baseHref + href; }, 200);
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else if (href) {
                            //assume internal link

                            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Internal', 'Click', href]);
                        }

                    });
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change this ligne : _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', 'Click-' + extension, filePath]); to 
ga('send', 'event', 'Download', 'Click', filePath);
and its working again for me